# Hashing images regardless of metadata

Tags: php, image, hash, imagick

My system accepts image files, of the following formats: **png, jpg, gif.** The same file may arrive to my system with different sets of metadata, and I need to uniquely identify them regardless of their metadata.

I’ve tried using the PHP module [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/es/book.imagick.php), reading the image, stripping them of metadata and then hashing them.

```
// example_image: https://ibb.co/bVkanv
$image_path = ‘example.jpg’; 
$stripped_image_path = ‘stripped_example.jpg’;

$img = new Imagick($image_path);
$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage($stripped_image_path);

$image_hash = sha1_file($stripped_image_path);
```

Nevertheless, this approach is not properly working, since the hash varies:

```
// example_image: https://ibb.co/bVkanv
$original_image = ‘Example.jpg’;

$image1_path = ‘example1.jpg’; 
$image2_path = ‘example2.jpg’; 

$stripped_image1_path = ‘stripped_example1.jpg’; 
$stripped_image2_path = ‘stripped_example2.jpg’; 

$imagick_1 = new Imagick($original_image);
$imagick_1->setImageProperty('Exif:Make', 'Imagick_1');
$imagick_1->writeImage($image1_path);

$imagick_2 = new Imagick($original_image);
$imagick_2->setImageProperty('Exif:Make', 'Imagick_2');
$imagick_2->writeImage($image2_path);

// Now example1.jpg and example2.jpg SHOULD be the same image with different metadata
    $imagick_1 = new Imagick($image1_path);
    $imagick_1->stripImage();
    $imagick_1->writeImage($stripped_image1_path);

    $imagick_2 = new Imagick($image2_path);
    $imagick_2->stripImage();
    $imagick_2->writeImage($stripped_image2_path);

    $hash = sha1_file($image_path); 
    $stripped_hash1 = sha1_file($stripped_image1_path);
    $stripped_hash2 = sha1_file($stripped_image2_path);

$hash
88f454a5f768d633f9d5b8fbba73cdc9dfa46f59

$stripped_hash1
fd385aa6ebcf8018a725598df945f925d8e05d58

$stripped_hash2
d9c9bca4f4433556d5c4c0d62ce06de06920e69b
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard Done!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with Imagick finally.

```
$image = new \imagick($path);
$hash = $image->getImageSignature();
```

Now, if in a same image the metadata changed, the hash will be the same.